# Request bot to reparse robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, web-crawler

I am writing a proxy server that maps youtube.com to another domain (so users can easily access youtube from countries like Germany without search results and videos being censored).

Unfortunately there was a bug in my `robots.txt`. Its fixed now, but Baiduspider got my old robots.txt and has been trying to index the whole website for a couple of days.
Because Youtube is a quite big website, I don't think this process will end soon :-)

I already tried redirecting baiduspider to another page and sending it a 404, but it already parsed to many paths.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Did you try to contact them (http://ir.baidu.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=188488&p=irol-inforeq)? How is the URL?

Comment: ok, thanks, i contacted them, the domain is mybaer.com (its currently redirecting every request to /robots.txt)

Comment: anyway, it think i will just let baiduspider make his stupid http requests, i dont have to process them, and maybe it will refetch the robots.txt someday

Comment: nice idea the redirect, but I think that the search engine won't parse this redirection. Why don't you simple add a .htaccess file which deny every access?

Comment: ok i did it..., i am using lighttpd, so it was something like this: $HTTP["useragent"] =~ "Baiduspider" {url.access-deny = ( "" )}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop processing requests from Baiduspider

with lighttpd append to lighttpd.conf

```
$HTTP["useragent"] =~ "Baiduspider" {url.access-deny = ( "" )}
```

sooner or later Baiduspider should refetch the robots.txt
(see http://blog.bauani.org/2008/10/baiduspider-spider-english-faq.html)